# Does this aggregate approach work efficiently with a millions of data?

Tags: r, unique, aggregate

I'm trying to get out of a dataframe/matrix the values that distinct some other values/classes.

i.e Here is an example initial table:

```
  P    |   V
------ | ------
par    | 123
par    | 1234
par    | 12345
par    | 123456
pat    | 123
pat    | 1234
pat    | 12345
pat    | 1234567
pay    | 123456
pay    | 789
pay    | 967
```

As you can see there are some values (V column) that are unique and distinct some of the values of the P column. These values are

```
  P    |   V
------ | ------
pat    | 1234567
pay    | 789
pay    | 967
```

and that is the expected output.

To get this, I used aggregate function (see bellow)) but the actual data are going to be much much bigger. They can reach 2-3 millions rows and maybe more.

Do you think that the following code is going to work and respond with such many data or there is another way to make it more efficient ?

```
mat = c("par","par","par","par","pat","pat","pat","pat","pay","pay","pay")
mat = as.data.frame(cbind("P"=mat, "V"=c("123","1234","12345","123456","123","1234","12345","1234567","123456","789","967")))

uniquePs = matrix(unique(mat$P))
diff = aggregate(P~V, mat, FUN=unique)
distinctVs = diff[which( grepl(":|," , as.character(diff$P) ) == FALSE ),]
distinctVs$P = uniquePs[as.numeric(distinctVs$P)]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you meant `lengths(diff$P)>1` instead of `grepl`

Comment: Yes. That could also work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a different approach you could use. It should be ok in terms of efficiency for 2-3 million rows:

```
subset(df, ave(as.character(P), V, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1L)
#     P       V
#8  pat 1234567
#10 pay     789
#11 pay     967
```

Here's an even simpler approach in base R:

```
subset(unique(df), !(duplicated(V) | duplicated(V, fromLast = TRUE)))
#     P       V
#8  pat 1234567
#10 pay     789
#11 pay     967
```

Comment: Than you very much both of you. I'll give them a try all of them and decide which is the faster.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps we need

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[uniqueN(P)==1], V]
#        V   P
#1: 1234567 pat
#2:     789 pay
#3:     967 pay
```